# How to type "This" using TypeScript and OLOO pattern with init function

Tags: typescript, oop, this

Per OLOO pattern, we need `init` function. For this reason I had to type "This" and add it as the first parameter of the function. Unfortunately, now I am getting an error on the `Autocomplete.init()` line saying that it is missing properties `input`, `url`, `listUI` and `overlay`.

```js
interface This {
  input: HTMLInputElement;
  url: string;
  listUI: HTMLElement;
  overlay: HTMLElement;
  wrapInput: () => void;
  createUI: () => void;
}

const Autocomplete = {
  wrapInput: function (this: This) {
    let wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.classList.add("autocomplete-wrapper");
    this.input.parentNode?.appendChild(wrapper);
    wrapper.appendChild(this.input);
  },

  createUI: function (this: This) {
    let listUI = document.createElement("ul");
    listUI.classList.add("autocomplete-ui");
    this.input.parentNode?.appendChild(listUI);
    this.listUI = listUI;

    let overlay = document.createElement("div");
    overlay.classList.add("autocomplete-overlay");
    overlay.style.width = `${this.input.clientWidth}px`;

    this.input.parentNode?.appendChild(overlay);
    this.overlay = overlay;
  },

  init: function (this: This) {
    this.input = document.querySelector("input") as HTMLInputElement;
    this.url = "/countries?matching=";

    this.wrapInput();
    this.createUI();
  },
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  Autocomplete.init();
});
```

I am not sure how to fix this as I need to type "This" to make this work. Otherwise it would throw an error that `this` doesn't have input etc.

Comment: Why not a class btw

Comment: I am able to do it with class, but wanted to see how it can be done using OLOO